# Objective C- Obtaining Page Screenshot/Image from URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an app that will take a csv file of URLs and should be able to display images of the URL pages that can be looked through.  I'm wondering if anyone knows a way in Objective-C to get an image of a page from a URL?  I know that it can be done with python and the qtWebKit, but I'm hoping that I don't have to write another script in python and that there is a way it can be done in Obj-C.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [this page](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/downloads) you find the link to the source of **Paparazzi!**, a Mac app written in Objective-C and using WebKit that does pretty much what you're after.

Its current version's (v0.5) source is not available, but up to v0.3 it is and should be enough to get you started (or at least give you an idea).

> Paparazzi! is a small utility for Mac OS X that makes screenshots of
>   webpages.
>   It’s written in Objective-C using the Cocoa API and the WebKit
>   framework.
>   It was inspired by webkit2png, a commandline tool written by Paul
>   Hammond in pyObjC.
>   http://derailer.org/paparazzi/

Comment: Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch has a lot of differences. This may not work.

Comment: Given that **Paparazzi!** is GPLed I wasn't suggesting to just copy/paste its code, anyway. ;) It however should give you an idea of how such a thing could be implemented. It may not work. No doubt about that. But this one can only know after getting one's hands dirty, for which **Paparazzi!** could be a good starting point, no?

Comment: This will definitely take some adapting, but it's worth looking into.

Thanks again